# Convert digital representation of a value into Arabic words

Tags: python, arabic-support

Convert the digital representation of a value to the equivalent words in the Arabic language.

An English language example would be:

- input = `111`
- output = `One hundred and eleven`

In my requirement `One hundred and eleven` is the Arabic equivalent.

Is there a python library for converting digital numbers to words in Arabic language?

Comment: You want, 123 -> one hundred and twenty three but in arabic?

Comment: Or are you looking more for 123 -> ۱۲۳?

Comment: There isn't one. You'll need to look for a dictionary (Python dictionary) online that can convert numerical values into string words in Arabic. You'll also need an algorithm for constructing them into Base10 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

num2words module in Python, which converts number (like 34) to words (like thirty-four). Also, this library has support for multiple languages. In this article, we will see how to convert number to words using num2words module.

Installation
One can easily install num2words using pip
pip install num2words
Consider the following two excerpts from different files taken from 20 Newsgroups, a popular NLP database. Pre-processing 20 Newsgroups effectively has remained to be a matter of interest.

from num2words import num2words

```
# Most common usage.
print(num2words(36))
  
# Other variants, according to the type of article.
print(num2words(36, to = 'ordinal'))
print(num2words(36, to = 'ordinal_num'))
print(num2words(36, to = 'year'))
print(num2words(36, to = 'currency'))
  
# Language Support.
print(num2words(36, lang ='es'))
```

Comment: Thank you I will give that library a try